# RoR: Swagger does not update api-docs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, documentation, swagger-ui

I have [swagger-ui_rails](https://github.com/d4be4st/swagger-ui_rails) integrated in my existing Rails app. I have added a new model "**Book**" in my application and now want to update my **api-docs**. How can I do that ?

I am trying `rake swagger:docs` but that does not change anything.
Also there is no **books_controller** in **app/controller/api/v1/** direcotry, where other controller exists already.

I am new to Rails and Swagger, so please ignore if i am missing something basic.

Comment: Are you using the `grape-swagger` gem? Do you have an API definition already? Did you mount the grape API inside your routes?

Comment: No I am not using grape-swagger gem. Yes I already have API definition.

Comment: Ok. How did you document your API? What defines the `rake swagger:docs`. The `swagger-ui_rails` gem just integrates the ability to "read" the API documentation, it will not generate it, definitely not if you are using home-brewn controllers. The grape-swagger gem will convert a grape API into swagger documentation automatically (that is why I assumed you were using that).

Comment: Ok, so I think here is the clue, home-brewn controllers. My existing API controllers must be hand-coded, and I have to do the same for my new model 'book' as well. Can I integrate grape-swagger gem at this point in my app? Will that create swagger documentation of all of my models automatically ?

Comment: If you use grape for your api, you can then use grape-swagger. Grape will replace your controllers for the API for you. I like this approach, I build a normal rails app, and use grape to serve the API part. My controllers for the UI and API would be different anyway.

Comment: I got your point #nathanvda. Thanks for explaining. I would accept your answer if you can post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention you define your controllers for the API, I presume you have a home-brewn API. This is ok, but then you will have to generate the swagger documentation by hand. That is ok, but not something I can help you with.

However if you use [grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape) for your api, you can then use the [grape-swagger](https://github.com/tim-vandecasteele/grape-swagger) gem. Grape will replace your controllers for the API for you. It is more like a DSL describing your API, which includes the code to be executed. The `grape-swagger` gem will automatically parse the grape definition and convert it to swagger documentation.

It offers extra options too, like write descriptions in Markdown. The `grape-swagger` gem is awesome :)

I like this approach, I build a normal rails app, and use grape to serve the API part. My controllers for the UI and API would be different anyway.